# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

Objects that occur in activity_main are null. 
I checked objects and IDs. I didn't understand what I couldn't see.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

Button buttonSend;
TextView textChat;
EditText texSendMessage;
ScrollView scrollView;
Login login;
TextView textSocket;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    login = new Login();
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));


    buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
    textChat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_chat);
    texSendMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_sendMessage);
    scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
    textSocket = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_socket);

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    String URL = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2";
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(URL)
            .build();
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback()
    {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException
        {
            if (response.isSuccessful())
            {
                final String myResponse = response.body().string();

                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        textSocket.setText(myResponse);
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    });


    buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Boş metin gönderilemez", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


    buttonSend.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (!searchString(texSendMessage.getText().toString()))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Boş metin gönderilemez", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            texSendMessage.getText().clear();
        }

        if (texSendMessage.getText().length() == 0 || texSendMessage.getText().toString().equals(""))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Boş metin gönderilemez", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e("TAG", "texSendMessage Boyut : " + texSendMessage.getText().length());
            textChat.append(Login.getShPref().getString("USERNAME", "null") + ": " + texSendMessage.getText().toString() + '\n');
            Log.e("LOG", "texSendMessage buttonSend : /" + texSendMessage.getText().toString() + "/");
            texSendMessage.getText().clear();

            scrollView.post(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, textChat.getBottom());
                }
            });

        }
    });

}

// arama fonksiyonu ile bosluk veya yeni satırların sayısını tutup
// sadece bosluk, sadece yeni satır veya ikisinden oluşan metinlerin gönderilmesini engeller.
boolean searchString(String s)
{
    String[] strings = s.split("");
    int count = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        if (strings[count].equals(" ") || strings[count].equals("\n"))
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count - 1 != s.length();
}

}
```

The output results in:

> Process: com.example.tunca.localconnect, PID: 31163
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tunca.localconnect/com.example.tunca.localconnect.MainActivity}: **java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
>           at** android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2858)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2933)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1612)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6710)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
>           at com.example.tunca.localconnect.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:86)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6980)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2811)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2933) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1612) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6710) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should be more specific in your question to have a chance to get a valauable feedback. See [ask] and give a [mcve] please

Comment: Thank you, sorry for first time

Comment: You might not have `button_send` in your `activity_main`. Also it seems like you haven't understood activities yet. You might want to read a bit more about it.

Comment: Please goto your res/layout/ find the directory activity_main and delete the activity_main.xml(v23)

Answer (score 0):

Clear your question first, It's a code which is not understandable but still, I can give you the ideas where you going wrong.

1. Why you have created the Login class which is not used anywhere,
   login = new Login();
2. This should be performed on click event, you have called in the onCreate method also The intent Activity class must be added into the Manifest file.
   startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));
3. Network call also should be called on click event.

Hope you get the idea about your error.